# Different way of writing multiple click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following `.click()` functions:

```
$('.tab').click(function(){
    $('.tab').removeClass('activeTab');
    $(this).addClass('activeTab');
});

$('.edit').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});

$('.cancel').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().prev().show();
});
```

*Is it possible to combine these functions doing something like this?*

**Pseudocode:**

```
$.click(function(){
    for $('.tab'){
        //do this
    }
    for $('.edit'){
        //do this
    }
    for $('.cancel'){
        //do this
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit">Edit</a>
<span class="controls">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cancel">Cancel</a> |
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="save">Save</a> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First off, I'd rewrite the HTML to get rid of the javascript `href` attributes. I'd also use a `data-action` attribute for the action name. You can still use class to do the styling of course, but style is not behavior, so keep those things separate (i.e. the class might be `action-button primary highlighted` or something, but the *action* would still be `save`):

```
<a href="#" data-action="edit">Edit</a>
<span class="controls">
    <a href="#" data-action="cancel">Cancel</a> |
    <a href="#" data-action="save">Save</a> 
</span>
```

Code-wise, what each link has in common is that they should `preventDefault` so the links aren't "followed" when clicked. So at the very least, we'll need this:

```
$("a[data-action]").on("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Then of course, there are the actions/behaviors themselves. I'd suggest putting the logic for each in an object, and expanding the generic click handler like so:

```
var actions = {
  edit:   function (event) { ... },
  cancel: function (event) { ... },
  save:   function (event) { ... }
};

$("a[data-action]").on("click", function (event) {
  var link = $(this),
      action = link.data("action");

  event.preventDefault();

  // If there's an action with the given name, call it
  if( typeof actions[action] === "function" ) {
    actions[action].call(this, event);
  }
});
```

Now you have a generic click handler, and an easily extensible list of actions. The action functions themselves behave exactly like normal jQuery event handlers (i.e. `this` will refer to the link clicked, and the first argument will be the event).

Comment: *slowclap* this was the answer I said japanFour should wait for!

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question directly: yes, it's possible to combine them into one function.

Is it advisable in the way you presented though?  No.

I would argue that anytime there's a function with hard coded functionality controls, something is probably wrong.

Consider this for example:

```
function someHandler() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('class-a')) {
        //do something specific to a
    }
    if ($this.hasClass('class-b')) {
        //do something specific to b
    }
    if ($this.hasClass('class-c')) {
        //do something specific to c
    }
}

$(".class-a, .class-b, .class-c").click(someHandler);
```

The easiest way to illustrate why this is a problem is to consider what happens if you want to reuse any of the specific functionalities.

How would you reuse the functionality in the `//do something specific to a` segment on something that doesn't have the class `class-a` without copying and pasting the code?  You couldn't.  (Well, not cleanly anyway.)

For this reason, it's good to try to separate functionalities and their bindings:

```
function someHandlerA() {
    //do something specific to a
}
function someHandlerB() {
    //do something specific to b
}
function someHandlerC() {
    //do something specific to b
}
$(".class-a").click(someHandlerA);
$(".class-b").click(someHandlerB);
$(".class-c").click(someHandlerC);
```

Now what if you want to reuse the functionality?  It's easy: `$("some selector").bind("some event", someHandler);`

Obviously in large applications it becomes a lot more complex than this.  There are of course times when it's ok to switch functionalities based on some condition.  It's typically best to keep different functionalities as atomic as possible though.  It relates back to the idea of separation of concerns.  Each segment of code should do only one thing, even if that one thing is just dispatching to more than one thing.

Comment: I agree with the TL;DR part. Separate handlers for separate ideas but the rest of this is not really an answer. Why are switch statements typically a bad sign? How can this be improved using this idea that the handlers can stay separate?

Comment: @JamesKhoury I should have been a lot more specific in my answer, I suppose.  A switch that controls the functionality of a function is typically a bad sign (or a switch-fallthrough type construct like his example uses -- not sure now why I read that as a switch).  It means that potentially disjoint functionalities are being crammed into the same place for convenience.  (Or, in some situations, because responsibilities are not placed in the right segments.)  I don't have time now, but I will update my answer later.

Comment: @JamesKhoury Have updated it to be more specific :).

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
$('.tab, .edit, .cancel').click(function(){
    switch(this.className){
        case 'tab' : {
            $('.tab').removeClass('activeTab');
            $(this).addClass('activeTab');
        }break;
        case 'edit' : {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).next().show();
        } break;
        case 'cancel' : {
            $(this).parent().hide();
            $(this).parent().prev().show();
        } break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I fixed your selector. But -1: your code still does not work. You can't switch on the element and expect that the comparison will magically check the class of the element.

Comment: @ANeves: Sorry, was 4:30am here whenI wrote it. I'll correct it now.

Comment: @ANeves I'll take a +1 now that the code works :) and again, my apologies for writing incorrect code...never code sans sleep.

Comment: This would fail if an element had more than one class.  For example: `<div class="cancel button"><div>`.  The `className` of that is `cancel button` which obviously does not equal cancel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but I think you can use your own manager in order to keep spaghetti code to a minimum.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8C5wR/1/

```
function ClickManager(element) {
 this.el = $(element);
 this.check = function(){
   if (this.el.hasClass('class1')) {
    console.log('class 1 detected'); 
   }

   if (this.el.hasClass('class2')) {
    console.log('class 2 detected'); 
   }

   if (this.el.hasClass('class3')){
    console.log('class 3 detected'); 
   }
   };
}

(function(){
    $('.class1, .class2, .class3').on('click', function(){
      manager = new ClickManager(this);
      manager.check();
    });
})();​
```

Maybe others can weigh in to point out possible fallouts of this.

Comment: Why can't we simply do `this.el = element`, or `new ClickManager(this);`? Also, you are recreating the ClickManager in every click; shouldn't it be done only once, and then `.check()` called repeatedly?

Comment: Right. I already change it to ClickManager(this). As for repeating the instantiation, well, yes, what about this? http://jsfiddle.net/ePYmz/. It required some changes but I don't know whether this is the right approach or not in situations where extensibility is needed. Is there a way to keep new ClickManager outside of every click call and yet being able to use something like this.el = $(element)?

Comment: Much better, IMO. (Well, but then you don't need the ClickManager, only the handler... sorry, I really don't like the question you're trying to answer.)

Comment: The `ClickManager` seems way overkill. http://jsfiddle.net/8C5wR/5/

Comment: @Corbin That's exactly what I want to avoid. Try to use that approach in a serious application and you will end up dealing with messy code.

Comment: @ANeves As I said before, we have to consider that something like this is going to be used in something with a good deal of functionality, so we need a manager. Although, I would like to know if there are alternatives that work in complex code.

Comment: @RobertSmith So rather than managing three handlers, you'd rather manager three handlers *and* their wrapper?  It's just adding complexity.  What if you want to use the handlers independently?  What if you want to only bind two of them at some point?  (Oh, by the way, part of the confusion might be the jsfiddle I posted.  I disagree with the code in that fiddle.  I think the proper way is as I said in my answer: leave them separate.  I just think if you aren't going to separate them, there's no reason to add yet another coupling.)

Comment: @Corbin The question here is not whether we are going to use three handlers or not, but how we are going to manage them. Obviously, if you want to provide more functionality, another solution would be appropriate. As always, this solution doesn't have to be the ultimate solution to every problem. Another solution would be to use different classes for each action, so you could reuse every class in different buttons, passing parameters depending on context. Of course, this assuming that you're going to do a lot in every action which may or may not be true.

Comment: @RobertSmith It sounds to me like you're jumping the gun with making classes.  These handlers don't hold state, so they don't particularly need a class-style context associated with them.  To each his own though, I suppose.

Comment: By handlers you mean each $('#something').on('click', ... right?

Comment: @RobertSmith Yes

Comment: @Corbin Oh, sorry, I meant to say "Another solution would be to use different methods for each action...". Having said that, not sure what you mean by '... (handlers) don't particularly need a class-style context...' Is that a kind of rule for using classes? A few months ago I wrote quite a bit of functionality for textareas and it worked just fine but as I was suggesting, that functionality wasn't focused on handlers but in providing methods and properties to a given object (in this case, textareas). It seems to me I couldn't have been able to do that using Flambinos' solution, for example.

Comment: Although for a small piece of code it's absolutely ok.

Comment: @RobertSmith In certain situations, like the one you described, I can see where that would be beneficial.  That is basically what jQuery is doing after all, and I think we can all agree that jQuery is doing it right :).  In the snippet in your answer though, the class *isn't* adding anything.  It's basically acting as a very thin wrapper around the `check` method.  If it's not adding anything, and it's making the API more difficult to use, why bother having the ClickManager class?

Comment: @Corbin It's not adding anything because it's an example. In a real situation, it would get methods and properties. That is when you get the benefits of using an object-oriented approach.

Comment: Even if I cede that point, your one check method should be 3 methods.  And, the hasClass should probably not be in the check method.  That could make sense in a few situations (like if the class were the code responsible for adding/remove the classes), but here it does not.

Comment: It could be. What are the other 2 methods? One for each class detection?